# Asking a question about someone else's working on another SE

Tags: discussion

I came across a [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102489/how-big-would-a-satellite-need-to-be-to-block-out-the-sun) on worldbuilding, one which was being debated in the comments. As far as I could tell the working made sense but I thought rather than listen to debates in the comments I could put it to the actual physicists.

I wasn't sure what the rules on that are though, would I copy the whole working over? Do I just point people to the link? (That seems a bit lazy) Is it seen as bad practice to make questions like this?

Comment: It's totally fine to post a similar question, i.e. "How big would a satellite need to be to block out the sun?". But this site is not for checking work.

Comment: @knzhou Its more to try to figure out who is right, the poster or the comments. It sounds like they both know what they're talking about.

Comment: (Worldbuilding mod here) Are you not convinced by the answers to that question? In particular, what do you feel is lacking?

Comment: @HDE226868 It was more that I was confused by the debate in the comments. I did [ask the question here on physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/380697/amount-of-light-blocked-by-a-body-at-the-earth-sun-l1-point) and got an answer that seems to fit the one accepted one in WB. It wasn't so much that I felt qualified to question either person only that both seemed convinced of their points and I thought people on Physics would be better equipped to clarify it.